# How to shorten code in Java/Android?

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to shorten this declaration code?

```
boolean installed1 = false;
boolean installed2 = false;
boolean installed3 = false;
boolean installed4 = false;
```

...etc

Comment: well, if installed can be represented a list of items (1, 2, 3, ...) you can use anything like `boolean[] installed = new boolean[]{false, false, false,..}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.Use *array* OR [`ArrayList<Boolean>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

```
boolean installed[] = {false,false,false,false};
//Access it by index i.e installed[0]
```

***OR***

You just want to decrease the code and it's class level declaration, as default value for `boolean` is `false`

```
boolean installed1,installed2,installed3,installed4;
```

If it's local declaration,

```
boolean installed1,installed2,installed3,installed4;
installed1=installed2=installed3=installed4=false;
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be the shortest way :

```
boolean installed[] = new boolean[4];
```